# How to randomize url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

url : http://localhost/dashboard/{random_string}/index.php

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9]{4}/(.*?)$ /dashboard/$1 [L,DPI]
```

but it still 404NF, can u help me?

Comment: So, ultimately, what do you want it to be rewritten too?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want `http://localhost/dashboard/{random_string}/index.php` to be be processed as `http://localhost/dashboard/index.php?id={random_string}`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteRule "^dashboard/([^/]+)/index.php$" "dashboard/index.php?id=$1" [L]
```